# Sending XML data from Objective C app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I want to send param's in XML format to a web service from Objective C app without getting an response (I don't need to handle with it). What is the best and fast way doing that?

Let's say I have the next XML:

```
NSString *xmlParams=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><R><Root><Grade>33</grade></Root></R>"];
```

And the address where to send the XML is : **www.myServer.com\service.asmx**

What is the implemention for sending `xmlParams` to that address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered a  similar question, so I'll just copy and paste some of that code here:

```
- (void)myFunctionToSendDataToTheServer
{

    MKNetworkEngine *engine = [[MKNetworkEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"myServer.com"];

    MKNetworkOperation *op = [engine operationWithPath:@"/service.asmx"];

    op.postDataEncoding = MKNKPostDataEncodingTypeCustom;

    [op setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler:^NSString *(NSDictionary *postDataDict) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<R><Root><Grade>33</grade></Root></R>"];
    } forType:@"application/xml"];

    [engine enqueueOperation:op];
}
```

I would suggest adding a third party library to handle the network code. In this case I used [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit).

The line of code that says "[engine enqueueOperation:op];" is the part that sends the request off to the server.
If you change you mind and do want or need to handle a response then add something like this before the "[engine enqueueOperation:op];":

```
[op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {

        NSLog(@"Successful response from server: %@", [completedOperation responseString]);

    } onError:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error from server; %@", [error debugDescription]);
    }];
```

Comment: Thank's, what this line: [op `setCustomPostDataEncodingHandler:^NSString *(NSDictionary *postDataDict)` actually do?

Comment: There are two ways to add your data to the request to get sent the the server. It looked like you were interested in POSTing an xml envelope. In that cause you need to set what you want to POST this way. I don't know if your server will accept this or not, I guess that's up to you to test.